# WPF - fill data on data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have the following code and I didnt find any way how to add the data from users 
to table .I want to do that dynamically .

I have create WPF application and add Data Grid and button and I that when I click 
on the button see the data on the data grid ,how should I proceed?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get user data...
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users Info");
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        string firstName = user.Firstname;
        string lastName = user.Lastname;
    }
```

The Xaml is:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest01" x:Class="WPFTest01.MainWindow"
        Title="WPF_DEMO_Main" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="#FF1BA1E2">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="185" Width="385" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged_1"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried with some of this code without success :(

```
//dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
//dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));

//DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign **users** (collection) as a ItemsSource of DataGrid to display the data on datagrid.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="500">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="#FF1BA1E2">
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="180" Width="385" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged_1"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
//Fill data here
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

            ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            users.Add(new User{FirstName = "firstname-1",LastName = "lastname-1"});
            users.Add(new User{FirstName = "firstname-2",LastName = "lastname-2"});
            users.Add(new User{FirstName = "firstname-3",LastName = "lastname-3"});
            users.Add(new User{FirstName = "firstname-4",LastName = "lastname-4"});
            DataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
}
```

That's it.

Alternatively you can define a collection property and bind it to DataGrid, instead of setting datagrid ItemsSource property from codebehind.

Answer (score 3):

First define a collection property:

```
// Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface correctly in this class
public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Get your data and fill this collection in response to the `Button.Click`:

```
foreach (User user in users)
{
    Users.Add(user);
}
```

Now `Bind` it to the XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
```

That's it!  When working with WPF, just forget about *doing it dynamically*... that's WinForms style.

---

UPDATE >>>

The simplest (but not optimal) way for a beginner to get this working is to define your properties and implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in the code behind of the `MainWindow.xaml` file. Next, add this into the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Ok, that's really it this time! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer a lot!! im new comer from Java ,can you please elaborate what should I do .where should I define the observer collocation and how ? where should I define the InotifyPropChange and how? Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

I always use this code to display/fill data in my Datagrid:

```
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From XXX;", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        con.Close();
    }
```