# Stack Overflow while binding DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, itemssource

I am trying to bind a `ObservableCollection` to `DataGrid`.

**CODE**

```
private void LoadData_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ObservableCollection<LoadData> LoadDataSet = new ObservableCollection<LoadData>();
        var items = new List<LoadData>();

        LoadData load = new LoadData("1", "1", "1", "1");
        LoadDataSet.Add(load);
        items.Add(load);

        loadDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

**in MainWindow**

```
public MainWindow()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;
}
```

**in Xaml**

```
DataGrid Name="loadDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="373,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="661" Loaded="LoadData_Loaded" /
```

Then I get an exception

> An unhandled exception of type "System.StackOverflowException"
>   occurred in xxxx.exe

Why is that not working ?

Comment: could u try this , LoadData method in MainWindow constructor and avoid the Loaded event.[Datagrid Reference](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control)

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: Hi, everything will work JUST FINE after I comment out
            //loadDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
But if I do 
ItemsSource="{Binding LoadDataSet}"

the program will run, except that the datagrid does not show anything. 

I did some research telling me to set LoadDataSet as a property, I guess this is it ?

Comment: I  tried to do this 
        public MainPage()
        {


            InitializeComponent();

            var items = new List<LoadData>();

            LoadData load = new LoadData("1", "1", "1", "1");



            items.Add(load);

            loadDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

        }
same thing still

Comment: referring to this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350886/wpf-fill-data-on-data-grid

I believe I did exactly what the best answer has said. But I still don't get why mine doesn't work

Comment: When an exception is thrown please have a look at the stack trace. Most often this will tell you what part of your code is failing. For instance, you may have a property with a backing field but by mistake the `get` method for the property will return the property instead of the backing field. This silly but hard to spot mistake will easily be spotted in the stack trace.

Comment: It looks like a recursion issue.  You need to unsubscribe to the loaded event.  Or refactor to a different event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't imagine what you have done wrong, I can show you how to do it right. Just create a public property for your collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<LoadData> items; 
public ObservableCollection<LoadData> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }
}

// Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface here!!
```

Then data bind that collection property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid Name="loadDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="373,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="661" />
```

Then finally, just populate your collection:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<LoadData>();
LoadData load = new LoadData("1", "1", "1", "1");
LoadDataSet.Add(load);
Items.Add(load);
```

Comment: But I realized the problem I had is not related to the view or the xaml themselves, it's my data... I created a cs file to generate data model but it didn't work. So I put the data class back into the MainWindow.xaml.cs file, and made the variables public. then it worked. 

I am still looking for a solution to extract the data model out

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.100).aspx) `Loaded` event occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

So I think when you set `ItemSource` of your `DataGrid` from `LoadData_Loaded`, it again raise the `Loaded` event of the `DataGrid` which results in and un-ending recursion and hence you are getting `StackOverFlow` exception.

You can try as [Eldho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876572/eldho) suggested. Instead of writing your code in `LoadData_Loaded`, write it in a function and call that function from the constructor of the class. Like below:

```
private void LoadDataInGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ObservableCollection<LoadData> LoadDataSet = new ObservableCollection<LoadData>();
        var items = new List<LoadData>();

        LoadData load = new LoadData("1", "1", "1", "1");
        LoadDataSet.Add(load);
        items.Add(load);

        loadDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
}

public MainWindow()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;
       LoadDataInGrid();
}
```